# How to insert a static image in Interface Builder for a Mac OS X app?

Tags: macos, interface-builder

I am just starting using Xcode and Interface Builder, so something as simple as to insert a logo as an image (.png), I just can't get my head around.

I know there's an ImageView, you can insert on an iPhone App, but I can't seem to find that component when developing a OSX App. So which is the best approach for inserting a static image to a panel in Interface Builder, do I use a Custom View?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can insert an image view (`NSImageView`) using Interface Builder. In some versions, the object in the library is called an "Image Well" for no good reason. Just search for "image" in the object library.